# Conversion of csv file to xlsx via Flow or SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow, csv, powershell-script

I have a Flow to store email attachments (in .csv format) to SharePoint. Now, I want to use the file in Power-BI from SharePoint. However, I want the file in .xlsx format. Could you please suggest how I can automate the conversion of the .csv file to .xlsx file format?

Thanks in advance. 
My google search results suggested methods of doing it offline whereas I want to automate it either in Flow or SharePoint if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps for conversion of csv file to excel through MS Flow:

1. After uploading the csv file in SharePoint, read its content. (Reference [link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Cookbook/read-csv-file-and-write-to-destination/td-p/258524)).
2. Create a CSV table using the output of csv file.
3. Create an excel file using that CSV table.

Comment: Can you elaborate on step 3?

Comment: Anyone else getting an error while accessing the link?    ______           'You do not have sufficient privileges for this resource or its parent to perform this action.
Click your browser's Back button to continue. '

Answer (score 0):

To fully automate this process you could throw an [Azure Function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) into the mix.

It would not be too complicated to create a (PowerShell) function that:

1. Read the .csv data from SharePoint using an app registration
2. Process the data
3. Create an .xlsx file using [Export-Excel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/)
4. Save this file back to SharePoint

This Azure Function can be triggered by your flow. Take a look at this example on how to get started: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning

(This is written about site provisioning, but it includes the bits you need)